# error_log doesn't work when using https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, error-log, wp-api

I have `WordPress` site which extends `WP_API` plugin to provide custom set of APIs. Everything works fine as intended, however, recently I implemented `SSL` to the site after which site has stopped recording logs.

I have wrapper function which uses `error_log` function to log custom activities such as when someones creates/edit/delete a record.

```
http://example.com/api/v1/documents (I can see my custom log messages in error_log file)
https://example.com/api/v1/documents (I can not see custom log message in error_log file)
```

Comment: The log file is probably somewhere else. Look into your apache configuration if in the vhost for 443 the ErrorLog path is different.

Comment: why would be log file different in case of https? I can see log file and entries when site is accesses via http, but no activity is recorded in log file when accessed via https

Comment: For the reason I explained: the apache configuration can be different in case of https. See https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebuggingSSLProblems#Enable_SSL_logging

Comment: Cool mate. Just figured out another file namely `ssl_error_log` in the logs directory which stores all the acitivies regarding ssl.